# Easy way to forward all email

Tags: email, smtp, mta

Is there an easy way to install a MTA on Ubuntu and forward all email to a different remote email box? Only want to forward local email and looking for something dead simple. Thank you!

**Clarification**:

I see that ssmtp and nullmailer are suggested, but I need something (just a) little more clever. I have one machine (machine.domain1.com) where I want local mail to be delivered at realuser@domain2.com and I want it delivered through direct connection to mx.domain2.com

So when I do mail root on machine1.com it should get forward to realuser@domain2.com. Issue with nullmailer and ssmtp is that forwarding is done to mx.domain2.com but mail is delivered with a RCPT TO set to root@domain1.com and I want the RCPT TO set to realuser@domain2.com

Possible with a simple solution or do I need to digg into postfix or exim for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's certainly no shortage of MTAs in Linux, nor in Ubuntu. As the most full-featured (and possibly overblown) solution, you can use `postfix` to relay emails to a provider - i.e. all the emails it receives will be sent via that SMTP server. [Here](http://prantran.blogspot.com/2007/01/getting-postfix-to-work-on-ubuntu-with.html) is a tutorial with details for Google Mail.

A more lightweight, and more simple alternative is `nullmailer`, although I'm not sure if it is capable of using all the secure transport methods required for Google Mail.

Finally, the easiest solution seems to be `ssmtp`. The setup is described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-gmail-as-a-smarthost.html).

Comment: Definetly `nullmailer` is the winner, the installer is asking for the minimal information and it just works after this.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't get much simpler than [nullmailer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nullmailer) [image: Install nullmailer]
. Although the mail will have to be sent to real addresses as nullmailer only forwards to a smart MTA.