# I have 5 hosts which i need to ping if any one down i should be alerted through an email it is possible..?

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, mail, ping

I have 5 hosts which i need to ping if any one down i should be alerted through an email it is possible..?
and it will be checked with every 20 minutes. can anyone help me.. Thanks in advance...

i have used this script.. Do i need to make any changes for getting the expected result ?

Please suggest any opinion please.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    for i in $( cat $HOME/iplist.txt )
    do
    ping -q -c2 $i > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo $i "Pingable"
    else
    echo $i "Not Pingable"
    fi
    done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need a good network monitoring tool](http://askubuntu.com/questions/192654/i-need-a-good-network-monitoring-tool)

Comment: For your answer, see Heemayl's answer (https://askubuntu.com/questions/758915/i-need-a-script-file-for-checking-ping-3-ip-address-are-working-or-not). The accepted answer below is rather kludgy and incomplete as it does not provide you with the mail notification you require.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks ok. You should add `exit 0` / `exit 1`, for failure / success .. more info below.

> and it will be checked with every 20 minutes

If the script should run always, each 20 minutes in the background, you should use `cron`, which is already available on your system.

Like that all output of your script will be mailed to root, if the script returns 1(FAILURE) .. however per default the root-mail just goes to some folder. You need to install & configure a mail-daemon to forward the root-mail to your personal mail-address. How that can be done is e.g. explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/306163/what-is-the-you-have-new-mail-message-in-linux-unix

Or here:
[Easy way to forward all email](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14879/easy-way-to-forward-all-email)

Edit:

Ok, here some commands to get things done.

1.) First you need a version of your script which exits 1 on failure. Something like this should do:

```
#!/bin/bash

ALL_HOSTS_AVAILABLE=true
for i in $( cat $HOME/iplist.txt )
do
   ping -q -c2 $i > /dev/null
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
      echo $i "Pingable"
   else
      echo $i "Not Pingable"
      ALL_HOSTS_AVAILABLE=false
fi
done

if [ "$ALL_HOSTS_AVAILABLE" = false ] ; then
   echo 'Some hosts were not available!'
   exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

2.) Now make sure you have sudo-permissions set for your user(you dont want to do things directly as root). If not, follow this manual:
[How do I add a user to the "sudo" group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group)
Maybe you first need to install the package sudo

```
su root
apt-get install sudo
```

3.) Copy your script to some folder which is visible to all users and hand it over to root. E.g:

```
sudo cp myScript /usr/local/bin
sudo chown root /usr/local/bin/myScript
sudo chgrp root /usr/local/bin/myScript
```

4.) Setup a cronjob which runs your script

```
# write out current crontab
crontab -l > mycron
# echo new cron into cron file */20 means each 20 minutes
# Check https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron for format
echo "*/20 * * * * /usr/local/bin/myScript" >> mycron
# install new cron file
sudo crontab mycron
rm mycron
```

5.) Install some MTA, so you get the email-notification working .. it looks like the most simple one is `nullmailer`

```
sudo apt-get install nullmailer
```

.. I dont know details, just google for help to do the `nullmailer` setup in the right way.

Comment: i am new to linux can u please give me the model syntax.....

Comment: ok, alot of syntax added

Comment: Removed "accepted answer" ? You found a better way to solve the problem ? If so, please share your knowledge. At least a upvote would be nice, if my answer was helpful.